# Rich Text - Redactor doesn't allow iframe even when in allowedTags config setting

Tags: redactor, richtext

I've updated my `craft/config/redactor/UserContent.json` settings with `allowedTags` containing `iframe` but `iframe` tags are stripped on save.

Other added allowedTags seem fine and iframe works on paste and initial editing, just not after saving.

Running Craft Pro 2.4.2679

I see there were issues with this for older versions of Redactor but they seem to be resolved. Any ideas about how to fix this?

Here's my UserContent.json:

```
{
    toolbarFixed: true,
    buttons: ['html', 'formatting', 'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'deleted', 'horizontalrule',
              'unorderedlist', 'orderedlist', 'alignment', 'indent', 'outdent',
              'link', 'image', 'video', 'table'],
    removeEmpty: ['p','strong','em','span','a'],
    cleanStyleOnEnter: true,
    plugins: ['video', 'table'],
    allowedTags: ['a', 'abbr', 'address', 'area', 'article', 'aside', 'audio', 'b', 'bdi', 'bdo', 'blockquote', 'br', 'button', 'canvas', 'caption', 'cite', 'code', 'col', 'colgroup', 'dd', 'del', 'dfn', 'div', 'dl', 'dt', 'em', 'fieldset', 'figcaption', 'figure', 'footer', 'form', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6', 'header', 'hgroup', 'hr', 'i', 'iframe', 'img', 'input', 'ins', 'kbd', 'keygen', 'label', 'legend', 'li', 'map', 'mark', 'menu', 'nav', 'ol', 'optgroup', 'option', 'p', 'picture', 'pre', 'q', 'rp', 'rt', 'ruby', 's', 'samp', 'section', 'select', 'small', 'source', 'span', 'strong', 'sub', 'summary', 'sup', 'table', 'tbody', 'td', 'textarea', 'tfoot', 'th', 'thead', 'time', 'title', 'tr', 'track', 'u', 'ul', 'var', 'video', 'wbr'],
}
```

Comment: Have you tried unchecking both "Clean up HTML?" and "Purify HTML?" in the rich text field's settings?

Comment: Yes, they are both unchecked. The rich text field is in a matrix field, if that matters in any way.

Comment: And you're sure that the RTE field you're testing with is using your custom redactor `.json` file in its field settings?

Comment: Yes. I checked the field settings again just now. I've tested with a variety of tags and they are all fine. I've edited my question to show the whole UserContent.json. Note that I also tried it without 'allowedTags' and get the same results, including after clearing Craft caches. It just doesn't like iframes - try it and if you find differently, please let me know. I have tested with YouTube iframes and another iframe with plain html content.

Comment: I just tested locally on the latest build of Craft both in and outside of Matrix in the latest Chrome with Craft's stock `Standard.json` file by embedding a Youtube iframe and it worked fine after saving the entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can, update to the latest Craft build. There was a Redactor update in [Craft 2.4.2682](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2682) back in July that updated Redactor and fixed issues with iFrames.

Comment: Thanks, Aaron. It's odd that Craft shows 1 update when there are actually 5 releases. Still, I should have looked for that more carefully.

Comment: @KennethBenjamin - that'll make more sense when the plugin store is out. Craft counts as 1 update, then another for each plugin that needs an update.